# How can one use a constant defined extern in another namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, extern, linkage

I'm grappling with variable linkage in C++.  Suppose one has:<sup>1</sup>

```cpp
namespace MyNamespace
{
    extern "C" const bool ReferToMe = true;
}
```

I expected to be able to refer to that constant from another namespace simply by namespace-qualifying the constant name, i.e. `MyNamespace::ReferToMe`.  However, that fails to compile:

```
error C2039: 'ReferToMe': is not a member of 'MyNamespace'
error C2065: 'ReferToMe': undeclared identifier
```

Why doesn't this work?  How *can* one refer to a constant that has been defined as shown above?

<sup>1. The preprocessor defines GUID constants in this way when type libraries are [imported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) with both the [`named_guids`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xybakhaa.aspx) and [`rename_namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t265fx.aspx) attributes.</sup>

Comment: I'm curious, is the `extern "C"` necessary here, and what is its purpose? I had been under the impression that that phrase was useful in determining calling conventions and linker symbols for functions, but I am surprised to see it applied to a data value.

Comment: @Logicrat: Certainly variables can also be declared `extern` (as with functions, it informs the linker that the definition is to be found elsewhere).

Comment: Is this all within the same file? If yes, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If not, have you declared that variable in the file where you're trying to use it? As with any name, it has to be declared to be used. Put `namespace MyNamespace { extern "C" const bool ReferToMe; }` in the other file (which is a declaration, but not a definition).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No, I hadn't!  That definitely makes sense, so thank you for that.  However, doing so now results in `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ReferToMe`... ?

Comment: Aah, my problem was that I didn't realise using `rename_namespace` caused the name of the `LIBID` GUID constant to be renamed in the generated TLH.  Thanks all.  Voting to close.

Comment: @eggyal `extern` for sure. but `"C"`? That's the part of it that is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think your must use **two** `extern` words, because first (`extern "C"`) means linker specification (no mangling) and second - externality of variable.
Try something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    extern "C"
    {
        extern const bool ReferToMe;
    }
}
```

or

```
extern "C"
{
    extern const bool ReferToMe;
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    const bool &ReferToMe(::ReferToMe);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed the footnote where I stipulated that the definition is in fact produced in this form by the preprocessor?

Comment: May be I don't get problem, because I'm not  familiar with Visual Studio. Also if it is autogenerated declaration, may be macro it provides is broken I think.